# Как реализовать API c одним общим аккаунтом?

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

### Введение

Есть проект ***project.com***. Хранит в БД аккаунты. API его размещен по адресу

```
api.company.com
```

Ничего необычного: авторизация, регистрация, выдача токена и работа с ним. По факту точка для создания аккаунта.

Есть проект, к примеру ***project.сom***.
Его API размещаем на

```
api.project.com
```

### Цель

Чтобы избежать тысячекратной регистрации, сделать **общий аккаунт** для всех локальный проектов. Т.е. чтобы авторизироваться на ***project.com*** должен быть аккаунт на ***сompany.com***, после ввода логина-пароля пользователю будет предоставлен доступ к локальному проекту.

### Как я себе это представляю

Буду говорить в рамках клиентов(сайт по сути тоже клиент) и API . Показываем на клиенте (допустим, мобильное приложение) окно авторизации. Он вводит пару логин-пароль (или входит через социалки).
Идет запрос на API авторизации:

```
api.company.com/login/.....
```

Если все в норме, сервер генерит-сохраняет в БД токен и отправляет ID и токен пользователю. Клиент сохраняет эту пару, и далее все запросы отправляет на API проекта:

```
api.project.com/users/3.....
```

прикрепляя токен-id.

При обращении к API проекта делается с него запрос к API авторизации по поводу валидной пары, и если все в порядке - работа в штатном режиме.

### Как я себе это представляю 2 (более красиво, но правильно ли?)

На клиенте показывается окно авторизации, вводится логин-пароль. Отправляется на API **проекта**:

```
api.project.com/login.....
```

API проекта выступает в качестве заглушки, и отправляет данные на API авторизации:

```
api.сompany.com/login.....
```

Если все в порядке - то API проекта возвращается, скажем, "OK", и далее API проекта выдает токен клиенту и работает уже с ним. Плюс в том, что не будет постоянного запроса к API авторизации. Красиво, но проблемы возникают по поводу безопасности (сменил пароль, к примеру).

### Вопросы

1. Может я изобретаю велосипед?
2. Что насчет Oauth 2.0? Мне кажется вариант не подойдет, так как редирект на страницу ***company.com*** не нужен,это закрытое API и авторизация доверенная.
3. Если то что я описал - более менее похоже на правду, то что посоветуете в плане улучшение архитектуры-взаимодействия?
4. Если то что я описал - бред, посоветуйте как организовать систему?

Спасибо!